# Cassandra 2.2 range slice timeout - request for suggestions

Tags: cassandra

I have a 3 node cassandra 2.2.6 cluster with two seeds that contains 100,000 records in one table. The replication factor is set to 3 and the consistency level is local quorum. The table has 7 primary keys and a clustering order of all but the first primary key. There are 11 indexes on 8 fields plus 3 dummy fields. One of the dummy fields is one of the 7 primary keys. Frequently, the request to delete a significant number of records (>65535), times out. The deletion request batches the records in groups of 65530 records before execution. I have increased the write_request_timeout_in_ms and counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms to 10000 (10 seconds). But when I try to delete the 100,000 records I get 2017-02-13 18:03:34,243 StorageProxy.java:1893 - Range slice timeout; received 1 of 2 responses (including data) for range 1 of 1. During the delete request, the CPU on the 3 machines max out around 100-130%. After the failure, the CPU on the cassandra machine that requested the deletion remains high for another 10 minutes.  I would appreciate any suggestions to limit or remove these timeout issues. Due to implementation issues, I cannot change the structure of the table. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you use smaller batches, maybe in parallel? Are you using unlogged batches? This is CQL right or are you using Thrift?

Comment: I am using a java interface (DataStax 3.0). I tried 1000 record batches but had similar problems.

Comment: "There are 11 indexes on 8 fields". secondary indexes? Not sure where to start but. 1) batches are expensive, not an optimization unless a very specific situation. 2) secondary indexes have a ton of gotchas, denormalization is almost always better.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Agree...this sounds like a whole lot of bad.